# Deployed Meteor App Crashing - WARNING MongoError: auth fails

Tags: deployment, meteor

Deployed on meteor.com, was working initially but now crashes.

[Meteor Deploy Status](http://status.meteor.com/) is showing no issues.

[Error Logs](https://gist.github.com/stevenmathews/b0955a3db3eb36fda2a3)

Not sure if this is affecting anyone else?

Comment: Have you tried to re-deploy the app?

Comment: I have redeployed and it's working. I'll update if it crashes again. Just wanted to document the issue in case it helps someone.

Comment: @AaronD I don't know enough to tell if it's the same error. Should I close this issue?

Comment: @StevenMathews It's hard to tell from the information you've provided. In both the linked possible-duplicate answer and this case, an app deployed on Meteor crashed with MongoDB errors. In both cases, it was caused by problems on Meteor's end, and solved by waiting and re-deploying. These questions are from the same time period (last 3 days). I don't think that this question/answer will provide any more information than the other one does, so maybe it should be closed. However, you can leave it open if you disagree and wait for community moderation to decide.